# Is this a suitable way to implement a lazy `take` on RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

It's quite unfortunate that `take` on `RDD` is a strict operation instead of lazy but I won't get into why I think that's a regrettable design here and now.

My question is whether this is a suitable implementation of a lazy `take` for `RDD`. It seems to work, but I might be missing some non-obvious problem with it.

```
def takeRDD[T: scala.reflect.ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T], num: Long): RDD[T] =
  new RDD[T](rdd.context, List(new OneToOneDependency(rdd))) {
    // An unfortunate consequence of the way the RDD AST is designed
    var doneSoFar = 0L

    def isDone = doneSoFar >= num

    override def getPartitions: Array[Partition] = rdd.partitions

    // Should I do this? Doesn't look like I need to
    // override val partitioner = self.partitioner

    override def compute(split: Partition, ctx: TaskContext): Iterator[T] = new Iterator[T] {
      val inner = rdd.compute(split, ctx)

      override def hasNext: Boolean = !isDone && inner.hasNext

      override def next: T = {
        doneSoFar += 1
        inner.next
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Suppose you have several transformations lazily applied to an RDD, how could you use `take` without applying those transformation? (maybe I don't understand lazy evaluations and RDDs well enough)

Comment: Simple. `take` is simply another one of those transformations lazily applied to an RDD. It says: once someone actually calls a strict operation (of which there should probably only be one, `collect`), then I will pass values given to me by previous transformations until I hit 5 and then signal that I am done providing values to whatever transformation might be following me. This is what I have attempted to implement above. To be clear, I am not describing how the Spark API currently works, instead how it could/should work. Does that make my intention clearer?

Comment: I don't get the point given in your last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer to your question

No, this doesn't work.  There's no way to have a variable which can be seen and updated concurrently across a Spark cluster, and that's exactly what you're trying to use `doneSoFar` as.  If you try this, then when you run `compute` (in parallel across many nodes), you

a) serialize the takeRDD in the task, because you reference the class variable `doneSoFar`.  This means that you write the class to bytes and make a new instance in each JVM (executor)

b) update `doneSoFar` in compute, which updates the local instance on each executor JVM.  You'll take a number of elements from each partition equal to `num`.

It's possible this will work in Spark local mode due to some of the JVM properties there, but it CERTAINLY will not work when running Spark in cluster mode.

### Why `take` is an action, not transformation

RDDs are distributed, and so subsetting to an exact number of elements is an inefficient operation -- it can't be done totally in parallel, since each shard needs information about the other shards (like whether it should be computed at all).  Take is great for bringing distributed data back into local memory.

`rdd.sample` is a similar operation that stays in the distributed world, and can be run in parallel easily.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Very informative. Despite it being inefficient, is there nonetheless a way to implement it? Currently we are using `rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(isIndexBelowTakeNum).unzip._2` (roughly) to simulate this and I can't imagine there isn't an at least slightly more efficient way of doing this then that.

Comment: You can certainly do something more efficient, but it's not going to be especially easy.  You need to: a) get the number of elements in each partition, b) take the first `n - 1` partitions as is, and c) load the last partition needed and apply a `take` to that iterator in the compute function.